# Multi classification with Random Forest - how to measure the "stability" of results

Tags: python, random, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am using Random Forest (from sklearn) for a multi-classification problem, with ordered classes(say 0,...,n, with n=4 in my specific case) roughly equally distributed. I have many observations (roughly 5000) and I split them in train/test 70%/30% respectively - the classes are equally distributed also in train and test. I set `random_state=None`, so each time I re-run the fitting of the model (on the same training set) and then the prediction, I obtain slightly different results on my test set.

My question is how to measure if **Random Forest** is working well by comparing different predictions...

For example if I obtain as predictions first only 0 and then only n (where, as said, 0 and n are the most different classes), I would say that the RF is not working at all. On the contrary if only few predictions change from a class to a close one (e.g. first 0 and then 1), I would say RF is working well.

Is there a specific command to check this automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is use cross validation. With this you will obtain a robust measure of general accuracy of the model.

Then you will train and test n different models (check this [link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html), it is pretty well explained). You can calculate the accuracy of each model, and then obtain the mean of these measures. And example would be (with 5 splits):

```
scores = cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=5)
```

And then plot the mean and std deviation of all of these accuracies:

```
print("%0.2f accuracy with a standard deviation of %0.2f" % (scores.mean(), scores.std()))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for this type of investigation we do not care whether the classifier made the right prediction, but we want to know whether it made **stable==consistent** predictions.

Assume `repeated_prediction` has shape: [repetitions,samples] and contains the predictions for each sample 1...n with multiple repetitions

What about:

`np.mean(np.std(repeated_predictions,axis=0))`

There are also papers that analyze the consistency of Random Forest's  e.g. [Consistency of Random Forests and Other Averaging Classifiers](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume9/biau08a/biau08a.pdf) but it seems to be a though read.